# Hybris how to index Variant in SOLR

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrj

I've started with Electronics accelerator which only indexes base products in SOLR. I have multiple Variant products (which extends from GenericVariantProduct) and I need to display them in the Grid/PLP. How can I change the SOLR indexer query in order to Index Variants too?

Comment: What is the actual query?

Comment: Where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query used for `electronicsProductType` :

```
SELECT {PK} FROM {Product} WHERE ({varianttype} IS NULL OR {varianttype} NOT IN ( {{ SELECT {PK} FROM {varianttype} WHERE {code} = 'ElectronicsColorVariantProduct'}}) ) 
                            AND {code} NOT IN( {{ SELECT {code} FROM {GenericVariantProduct} }})
```

In order to index all the product available on the database you can use the following query :

```
SELECT {PK} FROM {Product}
```

You can use the following Impex to achieve your purpose :

```
$solrIndexedType=electronicsProductType
$searchIndexNamePrefix=electronics

UPDATE SolrIndexerQuery; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique = true]; identifier[unique = true]        ;query
                       ; $solrIndexedType                          ; $searchIndexNamePrefix-fullQuery ; "SELECT {PK} FROM {Product}"
```

Adapt it to correspond more to your needs

Comment: Great! Thanks! BTW looking the OOTB query raised me a doubt, why they perform the second WHERE clause ? I'm refering to OR {varianttype} NOT IN ( {{ SELECT {PK} FROM {varianttype} WHERE {code} = 'ElectronicsColorVariantProduct'}}) ) 
                            AND {code} NOT IN( {{ SELECT {code} FROM {GenericVariantProduct} }}), It's not enough with : SELECT {PK} FROM {Product} WHERE ({varianttype} IS NULL in order to select only base products?

Comment: Actually, I am more trigger by the first clause, it's included in the second one